# HSQL Database Manager not coming up in Grails 2.0

Tags: grails, grails-orm, hsqldb, bootstrapping

Since upgrading to Grails 2.0, adding the line:

org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManager.main()

to BootStrap.groovy doesn't bring up the HSQL Database Manager like it does with previous grails versions. Instead an error is thrown:

```
| Error 2012-02-21 20:21:38,747 [Thread-6] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: No such property: org for class: BootStrap
Message: No such property: org for class: BootStrap
```

Has the name of this class changed? How can I get the Database Manager to start up with the application so that I can see the schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Grails 2.0,

> Grails 2.0 now uses the H2 database instead of HSQLDB, and enables the
>   H2 database console in development mode (at the URI /dbconsole) so
>   that the in-memory database can be easily queried from the browser

If you need HSQLDB, you may have to set up a runtime dependency